# How to close my own question?

Tags: support, status-completed, closed-questions

I asked a question yesterday and thought it is a different question from my previously asked another question. But now I am convinced that, actually it was a duplicate question. So, I wanted to close this question and redirect the users to my previously asked question. But I couldn't find any way to close this question. So I edited the title and add "[close]" tag there and edited the answer and add a link to the previously asked question.

Now, my question is: is that the right way to do this? Doesn't the questioner has any support to close his own question? If not, then can it be added as a new feature?

Comment: Users can vote to close a question, moderators can close them. They should be flagged as duplicate question and let the moderators deal with that. When you get rep of 3k (enough rep to 'vote to close') & 10k and 20k you have extra 'powers' to see extra info and help the community clean up the site. http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

Comment: @Mapperz May be you are misunderstanding me. I want to close my own question, not other use's questions. Or may be just want to make it a draft. I thought, it's something like editing my own question.

Comment: The way GIS-SE works you can only accept an answer. To Close you need to vote for it and that brings it to the moderators attention. You cannot close your own question directly.

Answer (score 8):

Flag your own question as a duplicate. That should draw it to a moderator's attention, and ultimately lead to it being closed.

Additionally, adding a comment that says something like "this is a duplicate of _ _ _ _ _" (where the blank is a link to the duplicated question) should draw extra attention for closure votes.